# 'font-variation-settings' difficulties

Tags: variables, fonts

I'm trying to get into variable fonts. I have made one that works perfectly in Safari, but whenever I use Chrome it makes my computer very slow.

This is my code:

```
.item{
font-variation-settings: "wght"0;
-moz-font-variation-settings: "wght"0;
transition: all .6s linear;
        &:hover{
        font-variation-settings: "wght"1;
        -moz-font-variation-settings: "wght"1;
        }
}
```

as you can see I want to inrease the wght whenever I hover.
This does not work in Firefox.

Maybe I am missing something, or I should wait till a patch fixes this for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: A good first check is to hit up "caniuse", to see what browser support is supposed to be. In this case https://caniuse.com/#search=font-variation-settings shows that FF sort-of-but-not-really supports it, but no notes for Chrome so it's possible you ran into a bug and you should probably file this on the Chromium bug tracker with a [mcve] so that they can confirm it's really the Chromium codebase doing something wrong.

Comment: I also ran into this issue on chrome. It works fine on safari, and works fine in chrome when removing the font-variation-settings rule.

Comment: Ok wow I asked this question one year ago :) I think it is because each glyph consists of many vector points and animating variable fonts is very heavy for the computer. I don't know how safari solved this from the beginning.